# Database sorting in pure C, binary files

Tags: c, arrays, database, sorting

I am currently writing a simple database in C. I have difficulties deciding how to sort the entries in a database. Lets say, we have a binary file with the specific structure consisting of fields and values.
As I understand, there are few different options:

1. Read everything from a file to an array of structures, then sort this array, then write everything back;
2. Read some entries from a file and sort them directly in the file (like, swapping them);
3. The other ways...

The first option is easier to implement, but it will cost quite a lot of memory, the second is harder, but there will be lots of read-write operations from/to the database file. How such kind of functionality is done in real life databases? Which option to use?

Also, [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35402849/sorting-data-in-binary-file-without-using-arrays) answer suggests to use 1'st option.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: before or later you have to load that in memory. the databases that are able to do the query locally on the file are not so much, and who is able brag about it. But a query very hardly weights more than few kilobytes.